# Is it possible to hook up a Component video cable (like those from the Wii) to an old TV that only has classic RCA?

Tags: video

I already manage to hook the cables, but my video is black and white.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a component to [composite video converter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/818178-REG/Atlona_AT_COMP500_Component_Video_to_S_Video.html).  It takes in the 3 component video connectors and has both S-Video and RCA out.  It should work for your needs.